# Symfony Global location

Tags: symfony, ubuntu

I need to install legacy Symfony 1.1.7 software. I need to install it globally.
I am using a Ubuntu 20.04 server.
The instructions - using pear or composer -  are outdated and do not work.
I can download the Symfony 1.1.7 tar file from Symfony legacy websites.
But what directory on the Ubuntu should I unpack it in so it is global?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still find the old (very old) docs on Github and they contain a getting started-guide helping with the setup: https://github.com/symfony/symfony1-docs/blob/master/getting-started/en/03-Symfony-Installation.markdown

In order to use this as a global installation, you need to copy the projects into the installation's `apps/` directory, e.g. `apps/frontend`.

Alternatively, you can try pointing the existing project's configuration to the new global library, and you can then throw out the dedicated library code in the projects. I am not sure how well this works, especially if the projects are built with different versions or have different configurations. Theoretically, you can do this by configuring the autoload to point to the right place:

```
// config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

You might also want to create a symlink to the Symfony command (`lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/symfony`) in your project directory.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, those were the instructions that I used to install Symfony locally - within the project directory. What I need are the instructions to install it 'globally'

Comment: Ok, then I’m confused what exactly do you mean by installing it globally? Do you mean multiple projects share the same Symfony-library?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added a section for configuring autoload. I am not sure if that is all you need to do. I haven't worked with Symfony 1 and don't know much about the setup, but hopefully that helps. If not feel free to continue the thread or update the question with the new details

Comment: Thank you - I saw where you added more info to your original comment. And it works pretty good. And in a very much older book for Symfony 2, i found all I needed to do  was to make a directory under /usr/local/bin called symfony   - /user/local/bin/symfony.  Then unpack the file there. And give the directory symfony a+x permissions!. Now I have 2 ways to do it. Thank you!